Using REGEXP or REGEXP_SUBSTR in an MariaDB query to extract all of the image source links
I'm trying to use REGEXP in an MariaDB 11.0.2 query to extract all of the image source links within the HTML and text of the field post_content that is in each row in wp_posts. I've looked at related questions but still can't get this to work.
My Regex works in a fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/CyuWhi/1
But using it in a query in Adminer 4.8.1:
SELECT post_content  
FROM wp_posts  
WHERE post_content REGEXP 'src=["|\'](.*?)["|\']';

returns the src links, but also other HTML and text. What I want is just a list of the image source links.
So, either my REGEXP is wrong for Adminer, or the structure of my overall query is not working.
Any ideas?
Edit: Barmar makes the good point that I should use REGEXP_SUBSTR. How would I do that?
The regex101 fiddle has sample row data and the regex. But I have thousands of rows in wp_posts and each has a post_content column that I want to search.
So would I use REGEXP_SUBSTR() with table data? I.e., example #4:
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-regular-expressions/mysql-regexp_substr/
But as in the example, all I need are the src URLs in a list, not the year.
The screenshot is of Adminer; the regex selects the row, but not just the image source URLs. (Image links are out of sight to the right.)


Why do you have | in the character sets? This will match src=|foo|, do you really want that?

It seems like you may be confusing square brackets with parentheses, e.g. ("|\') will match either " or '.

Or upgrade to a modern version of MySQL.

show example input and expected output.  you say "all of the image source links", implying there may be more than one in a given row; if so, include that in your input/output

@ysth Thanks! There are multiple img links in each post_content columns. The regex101 fiddle has sample data and the query, and the screenshot is of Adminer. So would REGEXP_SUBSTR "loop" through each wp_posts row and post_content column?

no, it wouldn't, at least not without more work.  I'd just do this in your client

Since MariaDB 10.0.5 I think you can use in REGEXP_SUBSTR (like @Barmar suggested in his comment)
a PCRE pattern. With \K  e.g. SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(post_content, 'src=[\'"]\\K[^\'"]+')...
or use a lookbehind: '(?<=src=[\'"])[^\'"]+'

Get rid of the ? lazy modifier, which isn't supported in MySQL 5.x regular expressions. It's also not needed when just testing for a regexp match, it's only needed when you need to determine the matching portion (as you might do with REGEXP_SUBSTR() or REGEXP_REPLACE() in MySQL 8.x).
SELECT post_content  
FROM wp_posts  
WHERE post_content REGEXP 'src=["\'].*["\']';

Note that MySQL doesn't use the PCRE library, so selecting that engine at regex101 may produce misleading results.

Thanks! Sorry, I checked for sure and I'm actually on 11.0.2-MariaDB (through PHP extension MySQLi ) and Adminer 4.8.1. Still no luck with your query; I still get what appears to be the entire post_content field. Does MariaDB make a big difference?

Why shouldn't it return the entire field? You're only using the regexp to select rows, not to extract a substring from the field. The error would be if it returns rows that don't have src="..." in it.

Use REGEXP_SUBSTR() to just extract the links from the HTML. SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(...)

The question was updated, it looks like OP uses MariaDB 11.0.2 (PCRE since 10.0.5)
